# how to solve org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchPhaseExecutionException: all shards failed

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch

I'm using elasticsearch

```
{
  "name" : "Angela Cairn",
  "cluster_name" : "prod-elastic",
  "cluster_uuid" : "iKkcI5FwTsGMtXacl3Qg-g",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "2.4.4",
    "build_hash" : "fcbb46dfd45562a9cf00c604b30849a6dec6b017",
    "build_timestamp" : "2017-01-03T11:33:16Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "5.5.2"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

sometimes I found below error and I'm not able to find the reason why it happens and what is the solution for same

### Error

```
Failed to execute phase [dfs], all shards failed; shardFailures {[3MNt6HxYSGiyfoZZhB20lw][catalog][0]: RemoteTransportException[[Angela Cairn][172.31.28.194:9300][indices:data/read/search[phase/dfs]]]; nested: SearchParseException[failed to parse search source [{"from":0,"size":15,"query_binary":"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"}]]; nested: QueryParsingException[Failed to parse]; nested: JsonParseException[Unexpected character ('t' (code 116)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries
     at [Source: [B@6f430fbe; line: 1, column: 238]]; }{[3MNt6HxYSGiyfoZZhB20lw][catalog][1]: RemoteTransportException[[Angela Cairn][172.31.28.194:9300][indices:data/read/search[phase/dfs]]]; nested: SearchParseException[failed to parse search source [{"from":0,"size":15,"query_binary":"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"}]]; nested: QueryParsingException[Failed to parse]; nested: JsonParseException[Unexpected character ('t' (code 116)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries
```

Comment: you see that in the exception? `QueryParsingException[Failed to parse]; nested: JsonParseException[Unexpected character ('t' (code 116)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries at [Source: [B@6f430fbe; line: 1, column: 238]]; }`

Comment: yes but i don't know what is the actual issue

Comment: is it any doc structure issue or something else ?

Comment: there is any syntax error in a query. You should find the query and fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main clue is provided:

> QueryParsingException[Failed to parse]; nested: JsonParseException[Unexpected character ('t' (code 116)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries

ElasticSearch is telling you that the query that you're trying to execute is an invalid JSON document.

The said query is this:

```
{ 
  "bool": { 
    "must_not" : [
      { "match":{ "status":"Inactive"} } ,
      { "match":{ "status":"Pending"} }
    ],
    "must": [
      { "match": { "location": "Delhi" } },
      { "bool": {
        "should": [
        { 
          "multi_match" : { 
            "query": "thionaid \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\",
            "type": "best_fields",
            "fields": [ "name^5", "brand^3" ],
            "boost":1,
            "fuzziness" : "AUTO",
            "prefix_length": 2
          }
        },
        { 
          "multi_match" : { 
            "query": "thionaid \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\",
            "type": "phrase_prefix",
            "fields": [ "name^5", "brand^3" ],
            "boost": 3
          }
        },
        { 
          "multi_match" : { 
            "query": "thionaid \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\",
            "type": "phrase_prefix",
            "fields": [ "sku" ],
            "boost": 5
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
  ]
 }
}
```

The problem is these strings: `"thionaid \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"` (one too many backslashes)

Comment: thanks, #robert can you please tell me how you got this query

Comment: @Devratna that query is written to the error log (as `query_binary`). It's just a Base64-encoded string containing the query.